# how to schedule notification when 3-days trial over in my app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am developing an app in which I am giving a 3 trial to the user.

So what all I want is to schedule notification when a 3-day trial is started and when a 3-days trial is over then the user gets notification whether the app is running or not.

ex:

1. 21-02-2020 Trail started then schedule a notification to date 24-02-2002.
2. on Date 24-02-2020 users get a notification in the morning related to trial is over.

so how to do this?
and which component I have to use like Service, Broadcast Receiver, Alarm or other?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show it once - them Alarm (AlarmManager.setExact) is fine, if you need to always show notification after 3 day delay - then `JobScheduler` will fit your needs.

If you decided to use `JobScheduler` api, here is snippet

your Application.onCreate

```
if (!applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("event", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isSet", false)){
    val jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

    jobScheduler.schedule(
        JobInfo
            .Builder(1, ComponentName(this, JobServiceImpl::class.java))
            .setMinimumLatency(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(3))
            .setBackoffCriteria(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1), JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
            .build()
    )
    applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("event", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isSet", true)
}
```

JobServiceImpl

```
class JobServiceImpl : JobService() {
    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        //show your notification here

    jobScheduler.schedule(
        JobInfo
            .Builder(1, ComponentName(this, JobServiceImpl::class.java))
            .setMinimumLatency(TimeUnit.Minutes.toMillis(1))
            .setBackoffCriteria(TimeUnit.Minutes.toMillis(1), JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
            .build()
    )
    }
}
```

don't forget to update manifest

```
<service
            android:name=".JobServiceImpl"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```